# How to adjust the section numbering (as in skipping a couple of section numbers) when using letters instead of numerals for section numbering?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

I have changed the section numbering from numerals to letters with the command

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alph{section})}
```

in the preamble. For example, the first `\section{}` would be printed like this in the pdf:

**a)**

I am interested in skipping a couple of sections in the document. For example, lets say  sections **b)** and **c)** such that the section numbering after **a)** would be **d)**. Thus the result of another `\section{}` command in the preceeding example would render the following output in the pdf:

**a)**

**d)**

How can this be done in LaTeX?

Best regards,

Gus

Comment: Hi and welcome, you could simply issue two `\stepcounter{section}` or set the counter with `\setcounter{section}{4}`. But i guess there is logic behind this, so there might be a different (and better approach). Can you explain why you want to skip?

Comment: `\addtocounter{section}{2}` after the first section does the same effectively as using `\setcounter{section}{4}` and is independent of the current section number (which is not the case for `\setcounter{section}{4})`

Comment: Note the internal counter is still a number so you can set it add to it, etc, it is just the final printing of the number that is alphabetic

Comment: Johannes_B. I am writting solutions to a textbook that does not have solutions to all questions.

Comment: @Christian. It was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alph{section})}


\begin{document}

\section{First}

\addtocounter{section}{2}

\section{Second, but counted as fourth}

\end{document}
```

Another approach uses more 'configurability':

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alph{section})}

\newcounter{sectionstoskip}
\setcounter{sectionstoskip}{2}

\begin{document}
    \section{First}
    \addtocounter{section}{\value{sectionstoskip}}
    \section{Second, but counted as fourth}
    \addtocounter{section}{\value{sectionstoskip}}
    \section{Third, but counted even otherwise}
 \end{document}
```

If the sections should not be skipped any more, just use `\setcounter{sectionstoskip}{0}` in the beginning.

[image]